# grails taglib get a list from controller

Tags: grails

I came across a post from Donal which I think was asking he same thing but did not really anwer the question, a little puzzled and wonder if possible.

If I have a tag lib, user provides controller action I Wish for it to then go off query controller and return result as a list, I tried g.include with no luck.  I have tried to expand on this below but don't know too much about it and if at all possible to actually get a value back from the given primaryAction or def value within controller

```
if (attrs.primaryController && attrs.primaryAction ) {
                //def nlist= g.include(controller:'${attrs.primaryController}', action:'${attrs.primaryAction}',  id:'${attrs?.primaryId}')

                def controllerArtefact = grailsApplication?.getArtefactByLogicalPropertyName("Controller", "${attrs.primaryController}")
                def controllerClass = controllerArtefact?.getClazz()
                def aaa=controllerClass.declaredFields.each {
                     it.name=="${attrs.primaryAction}" } 

                    println "-->"+aaa.getMetaPropertyValues().


                println "-------------????? ${aaa}"

}
```

I also thought maybe another way would be for the controller that loads up the gsp which contains the taglib should easily be able to pass a list as a variable down to the taglib, the taglib then takes attrs.newList and represents it as List.

Doing things this way the plugin was complaining about no id, really bizzare since the typical list produced from within plugin looked identical.

Comment: It seems to me that what you really want is some kind of AJAX functionality. Because a taglib is executed on the server during the original request it can't respond to user interaction once the page is loaded. So the processing you are talking about may as well be done by the controller that is serving that page (in a service). But if you want the user to interact with the page and then part of the page to change, then you have to use AJAX and call another controller to send back the "results list". You should never need to call a Controller in a taglib!

Comment: Hi Nicdos, thanks for the feedback, although I doubt this is going to be possible, in short this is within a plugin and the end user can send any given controller/action within their own project. The provided action/controller would then not render but rather return a list. https://github.com/vahidhedayati/ajaxdependancyselection/issues/7

Comment: Unless your code is directly interacting with the `HttpServletRequest` and is using a GSP to render output, you should be using a `Service` instead. Your `taglib` can easily be injected with a service (just `def myService` at top of taglib) and then it can generate the results list (return type `List`) which the `taglib` can render. No need to use `getArtefactByLogicalPropertyName`, etc...

Comment: Thsnks Nick plugin is alteady doing this based on domainclasses provided by them when they call within gsp. This was a request by end user. To instead provide values via own controller. So in essence I can not inject their service since plugin is already built. I was trying see if it was possible

Comment: Ok managed to resolve this issue now - the user can define their own list and pass it to the tag lib. Had a relook at the issue and think it was because I had forgot to set the search/CollectFields correctly in my previous attempt. supported as part of 0.42 ajaxdependancyselection plugin